# AVD of xxhdpi device doesn't start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have to emulate an HTC One, so I set a Device like this:

[image]

But, when I start the AVD, the AVD goes black, and doesn't boot.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Give it a few minutes, up to 10.

Comment: What kind of image you're using? ARM or x86?

Comment: Show the next screen.  Be sure to check "Use Host GPU".

Comment: @Rick Falck Oh, thanks! Didn't see it! :) Now works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your monitor doesn't have that many pixel per inch. To start it when you launch the emulator select scale display to real size ,click on the question mark and select the monitor's screen size in inch and resolution, it will then automatically calculate monitor dpi. Also edit emulator to make use of host GPU as others have suggested. If your GPU is weak the screen of the emulator may blink and it will be even slower than normal emulators.

Comment: how much ram have you assigned to it ?